# How do you change the colours used in the annotate bar in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, annotate

I am using a custom colour scheme in Visual Studio 2008. The annotate bar (that shows who checked each block of code in and when) is rendering in some illegible colours. I can't identify which colours these are within the relevant Options dialog so I cannot change them to something clearer.

Does anybody know how to change these colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations is only available in the Visual Studio Team System through TFS. It can be hard to read sometimes because the background is a gradient, which, depending on your settings, may fade to the same colour as your font.

Unfortunately there is no way to exclusively change the font and background of the Annotations bar. When you change the Font and Colors in your options, Annotations will change along with the settings in your text editor.

You have two options that I can see:
1. Change your settings in Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors so that the background of Plain Text is a strong contrast with the colour of the font in your annotations, or enlarge the font size. These changes will affect the background gradient and font size of the annotations bar.
2. You can download the Team Foundation Server Power Tools and access this information on the command line with **tfpt annotate**.